# Avoiding strange results with most comparison operators with read-from-string

Tags: common-lisp, comparison-operators

I am using an implementation of common lisp called CCL and I have run into a strange issue that I do not quite understand.

When I call:

```
(read-from-string "(=)")
```

I get a list containing the equal operator:

```
(=)
```

But when I call:

```
(read-from-string "(<)")
```

I get a backslash in front of the <:

```
(\<)
```

I find this quite confusing and I am wondering if this may be specific to my implementation or is this an intended part of the spec?  Why would this \ show for < and > but not =?

Is there anyway to avoid the backslash?

Comment: Its an implementation called Clozure CL a descendant of MCL.

Comment: And it does mess with some later parsing.  Why would the "<" be escaped but not the "="?

Comment: Well the problem is that this is being turned into xml so "<" needs to be turned into "&lt" and "\<" turns into "\&lt" which is not correct.

Comment: (1) Is the backslash really there or is it just getting printed as being there?  (2) you should probably have a layer of XML generation above read-from-string

Comment: No escape there for me on `Version 1.9-dev-r15611M-trunk  (LinuxX8632)`. Does this happen in a fresh REPL?

Comment: You're right Daniel this seems to only be happening in 1.9-dev-r15462M-trunk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backslash is just a presentation issue.

When you do `(mapcar #'symbol-name (read-from-string "(<)"))` you probably get `("<")`, so you *are* getting the right symbol.

If you want, you can report this as a bug to the CCL maintainers, since this backslash is a (minor) deviation from the ANSI CL standard.